# How do I layer a widget over another widget in an Android GridLayout?

Tags: android, widget, grid-layout

## Problem

In Android Studio 3.0.1, I am creating a screen with a GridLayout. Within this GridLayout there are three TextViews and an ImageView.

Here is a visual perspective of the ComponentTree I am describing:

[image]

I want the three TextViews to be a layer down from the ImageView, so that that three TextViews are superimposed on top of the ImageView.  From what [I've read about GridLayouts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), there doesn't seem to be a mention of layering. In addition, for TextViews the only tag related to layers [has nothing to do with visual display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layerType).

## Question

Is there a way to layer the ImageView in between the TextViews and the GridLayout?

Comment: Use FrameLayout and put ImageView as first child and GridLayout as second child into it.

Comment: That worked, I had had a larger system than the tree depicted, but alternating frame layouts solved my issue.